# JSON Encode PHP

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

So this is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 150);
require('db.php');

$values = array();
$data = array();
$username = $_GET['username'];
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
$password = $_GET['password'];
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT premium_duration, vip_duration
FROM 
users_account
WHERE 
user_name='".$username."' 
AND user_pass='".md5($password)."'
");
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    if($row['premium_duration'] > 0)
    {
        $timeremain = $row['premium_duration'];
        $type = 'Premium';
    }elseif($row['vip_duration'] > 0)
    {
        $timeremain = $row['vip_duration'];
        $type = 'VIP';
    }else{
        $timeremain = 0;
        $type = 'None';
    }

    $values['TimeRemain'] = $timeremain;
    $values['Type'] = $type;
    $data[] = $values;  
}

echo json_encode(array("Durations" => ($data)));
?>
```

But it only results to:

> {"Durations":[{"TimeRemain":"15847800","Type":"Premium"}]}

What I want to achieve is:

> {     "Durations"       {           "TimeRemain":74973600,          "Type":"Premium"
>         },      {           "TimeRemain":0,             "Type":"VIP"        }   ] }

How I can do that?

Comment: are you sure you have two rows in query result set?

Comment: @ksiger yes I want to parse both what I want to achieve is { "TimeRemain":74973600, "Type":"Premium" }, { "TimeRemain":0, "Type":"VIP" } ] }

Comment: Please read a bit about database security and sql injection. You should use prepared statements and you should never use md5 for password hashing.

Comment: set a counter in your while and print it after while to know while work how many time.

Comment: You have to check how many row you getting from DB using that : mysqli_num_rows ( $query );

Comment: @apokalypto, you cant get object `{ "TimeRemain":0, "Type":"VIP" }` at all. You set type to "VIP" only when vip time more than 0. Can you print dump of query result?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.